# Why try_files? (prerender.io nginx )

Tags: nginx, prerender

I can't understand the [official nginx conf](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802) of the https://prerender.io

Why try_files?

Using `try_files` the `location @prerender` will never be fired!

I was looking the following behaviour:

> If any page is accessed from the browser, nginx serve it statically/locally. If that page is accessed from some crawler, it's served by the proxy.

The official snippet seems not to do that, but the official doc says that:

> The Prerender.io middleware that you install on your server will check each request to see if it's a request from a crawler. If it is a request from a crawler, the middleware will send a request to Prerender.io for the static HTML of that page. If not, the request will continue on to your normal server routes. The crawler never knows that you are using Prerender.io since the response always goes through your server.

Can somebody help me to understand that?

Answer (score 0):

Todd from Prerender.io here.

We suggest using try_files like:

```
try_files $uri @prerender;
```

This was done so that $uri could match static files (images, etc) and then, if not found, run the @prerender config.

Sometimes we see $uri matching /index.html for every request to return the html file for your single page application. If that's the case, you can remove the try_files and instead just copy the contents of the @prerender location to wherever you need it to be so that it runs before your index.html file is served.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why "if not found"?. People use to share a valid link (open graph meta tags case). If a crawler scan an invalid page, it should receive 404. Why to proxy only invalid requests? I didn't get the point.

Comment: Most single page applications have a "catch-all" that just returns an index html page with a status code 200. Usually the check on whether a page is valid or not is done by the javascript with SPA's. So the "@prerender" config runs and tries to check if the request is coming from a crawler. If so, it proxies the request to Prerender.io. If not, it serves an /index.html file using a rewrite in the "@prerender" config.